# linq query showing long doesnot contains definition for Contains while converting sql query to linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

friends we are converting sql query to linq query, this conversion is involving two tables as follows

```
select * from Tbl_Vulpith_Registration where Profile_Pic is not null and MemId IN(select MemId from Tbl_List_Services)
```

here Tbl_Vulpith_Registration  and Tbl_List_Services both are the tables

memId is the common column in the both the tables.

following the what we tried to convert the above sql query to linq

```
var reglist=  objentity.Tbl_Vulpith_Registration.Select(a => a).Where(a => a.Profile_Pic != null);
// var res= reglist.Where(a=>a.Tbl_List_Services)

var listmemsmemIds = objentity.Tbl_List_Services.Select(b => b.MemId).ToList();

var finalist = reglist.Select(b => b).Where(c => c.MemId.Contains(listmemsmemIds));
```

We've tried multiple ways to convert but no luck.

Comment: Using Join, there would be only query will be formed and fetched from database. The current code (when it works) forms two query to fetch the required data.

Comment: I've posted a solution using Join, check that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the exact opposite:

```
.Where(c => listmemsmemIds.Contains(c.MemId))
```

Comment: hi @Peter, thanks for the reply.. still this is not working, can you pls eloborate whole query, can you pls rewrite.

Comment: I forgot to start the expression with `c =>`, added it, please check again

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code which join two tables and fetch the output (internally, it will create only one query)

```
var reglist = objentity.Tbl_Vulpith_Registration.Join(objentity.Tbl_List_Services, 
     o => o.MemId, i => i.MemId, (o, i) => o).Where(o => o.Profile_Pic  != null).ToList()
```

The above code correlates the tables based on matching `MemId` and return the object of entity type of `Tbl_Vulpith_Registration`.

If you want to read about Join method, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx) link.